# Unable to center button: what am I missing?

Tags: html, css, button, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a few animated buttons on my page.  I stepped away from this project (and code in general) for a while.  There is 12px of padding that is causing the hamburger to shift to the right, creating a look that is awfully unaligned.  I wouldn't doubt that it is something farther down the line in the code, but I'm just looking for any kind of direction at this point because nothing I try seems to work.  If I am missing parts of the code that would aid in figuring out what the issue is, just say the word and I'll point out what's needed.

I would have posted a screeshot of the issue, but my reputation points are not high enough...  That said, the developer tools are telling me it's ~12px of padding from bootstrap.  More specifically it says:

```
padding: .25rem .75rem
```

Could've sworn if I specify something it overwrites bootstrap...

My apologies if this is a total noob question, or asked in a total noob way, I've never posted on stackoverflow before.  I've tried to search for an answer, but I can't find anything that helps.

The button is sitting in a fluid container which is inside a flex-column, but I'm not sure that matters because it appears as though the 12px of padding is the issue.

I've tried position, various versions of align, adjusting the padding/margins/border, and all of the above on various surrounding items: changing anything only makes it worse.  The following is my css:

```
.nav-btn {
    width: 50px;
    height: 32px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
}

.nav-btn span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    height: 4px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Here is some of the html, I tried to trim as much as I could...

```
<main class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <aside class="col-md-3">
            <div class="flex-column">
                <button class="navbar-toggler flex-column nav-btn">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                </button>
```

I need the hamburger to align vertically with the rest of the page (and by "the rest of the page" I mean "the rest of the aside class=col-md-3 after stacking itself onto section class=col-md-9 when shrunk down past 768px for the width of any given screen", but TL/DR amiright?).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sure there's always a better way to do something too, so by all means; there's always a "better" way to do eavneyrything.

Comment: Can you include your `HTML`?

Comment: margin: auto; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; or you could manually center it with margins. If you want more help please include your HTML!

Comment: If setting `margin: auto` doesn't work then you can try overriding the padding from bootstrap by setting `padding: 0px !important` on the hamburger menu.

Comment: @CallumR !important didn't work =/

Comment: 80% width for the span of the 50px width stated in the nav-btn turns out to be about 40px.  I changed the width of the nav-btn to 40px and width of the span to 100% to just fill the box.  This "solved" the issue, but was more of a manipulation than an answer.